# iOS Chrome Address bar and fixed div issue

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

This question has two parts.

The first question is why does the iOS Chrome address bar scroll out of view on some websites and not on others?

E.G. The address bar on http://getbootstrap.com is fixed whereas on https://uk.yahoo.com is scrolls up.

What is triggering this behaviour?

The second part of the question is that I'm trying to create a full screen fixed left hand menu slide out.

The problem is that when the page scrolls, the left hand menu scrolls up too leaving a 60px gap at the bottom.

Can you suggest any workarounds to solve this problem?

Thank you!